# How to identify whether a process is hanging?

Tags: unix, process

In unix, if we see that some process is utilizing more cpu time, then how to identify if that process is hanging or not?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to solve the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)?